# Understanding the response from Graphite render interface

Tags: graphite

When getting a JSON response from Graphites `/render` API it looks as follows.

```
{
"target": "summarize(sol.count.meter.count, "1day", "sum")",
"datapoints": [
  [
  null,
  1481846400
],,
  [
  null,
  1481932800
],,
  [
  null,
  1482019200
],,
  [
  null,
  1482105600
],,
  [
  null,
  1482192000
],,
  [
  null,
  1482278400
],,
  [
  1006491,
  1482364800
],,
  [
  1577,
  1482451200
],
],
}
```

My intuition about the expected response is that I would get a list with datapoints, where each day has 0 or 1 measure. However this is not what I get.

What I dont understand is why we need a nested list to represent datapoints? What is the content of the inner list in a Graphite response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graphite's json output format can be defined as **array of metric series**, each **metric series is an object** with the series' id/name called **target** and **array of datapoints**, and finally each **datapoint is a array of corresponding value and timestamp**.

```
[
  {
     "datapoints": [
       [value1, timestamp1],
       [value2, timestamp2],
       // ...
     ],
     "target": "some.metric.count"
  },  {
     "datapoints": [
       [value9, timestamp99],
       [value8, timestamp88],
       // ...
     ],
     "target": "some.metric2.count"
  },
  // ...
]
```

This structure is a result of design concept and its implementation:

- datapoint must contain value and timestamp (time frames are **aligned on render** and could it be adjusted) and array is the lightest structure
- datapoints must be an array to preserve the order, since object is a hash-like structure. Note that **each series can have very different timestamps**, but have **particular order and the same length** (nulls if no values found)

> My intuition about the expected response is that I would get a list with datapoints, where each day has 0 or 1 measure. However this is not what I get.

`summarize` reduces (using sum/avg/max/min) datapoints per specified time bucket, if all values in buckets are nulls, the final value equals to `null`. You can use [`transfomrNulls`](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.transformNull) to replace nulls with desired value.

Comment: But how can you know if it is the timestamp or the value in an array? Order is not fixed by the JSON standard to my understanding so relying on that head is value and tail i timestamp would be too loose???

Comment: Array order is fixed. At index 0 is value, at 1 is timestamp.